# How to handle, check if user is logged in with Passport Slack Strategy and Passport-local

Tags: node.js, passport.js, passport-local

Hello I am needing some assistance with setting up a function to check if a user is logged in or not with Passport.js using the slack strategy.

I have a localstrategy which works fine but I also want to implement a sign in with slack as well.

I have added my app to slack and set the redirect URL. Everything is working fine however regardless if a user signs in or not they can still access the main page from the URL.

Example I have my login page 123.456.7.891:3000/login and when a user logs in through the local login or slack it redirects to 123.456.891:3000/index. Well if you know the URL for index you can just navigate to it.

For the local strategy I used this function to prevent that. It checks if the user is logged in or not.

```
  function isLoggedIn(req, res, next){
  if(req.isAuthenticated()){
      return next();
  }
  req.flash("error", "Must be signed in first to access this page.");
  res.redirect("/login");
}
```

And than I simply add the isLoggedIn function to the route like this.

```
app.get("/QAApplicationHub", isLoggedIn, (req, res) => {
Application.find({}, (err, allApplications) => {
  if(err){
      console.log(err);
    }  else {
      res.render("index", { application: allApplications });
      // username: req.user.name
    }
   });
 });
```

The issue I am having with when a user logs in with slack is when they are redirected to the redirect URL it just takes them back to the login page stating that the user must be logged in to access the page. The message appears because I have flash set up to show the user the error. It seems that with my current code the isLoggedIn only checks for the local login and not slack.

So how can I implement the isLoggedIn function for both the local and slack strategy? Or what method is it that I need to implement for it to work for both.

This is my code for Passport-slack.

```
  // Configure the Slack Strategy
  passport.use(new SlackStrategy({
    clientID: process.env.SLACK_CLIENT_ID = '123456',
    clientSecret: process.env.SLACK_CLIENT_SECRET ='123abc',
    }, (accessToken, scopes, team, extra, profiles, done) => {
    done(null, profiles.user);
  }));

 //=============================
//LOCAL LOGIN MIDDLEWARE
//=============================
app.post("/login", passport.authenticate("local", {
  successRedirect: "/QAApplicationHub",
  failureRedirect: "/login",
  failureFlash: true
}));

app.get("/logout", (req, res) => {
  req.logout();
  req.flash("success", "Successfuly signed out!")
  res.redirect("/login");
});

// =============================
// PASSPORT-SLACK MIDDLEWARE
// =============================
// path to start the OAuth flow
app.post('/auth/slack', passport.authorize('slack', {
  successRedirect: "/QAApplicationHub",
  failureRedirect: "/login",
  failureFlash: true
}));

// OAuth callback url
 app.get('/auth/slack/callback',
   passport.authorize('slack',
     (req, res) => {
     res.redirect('/QAApplicationHub')
   }));
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe users are stored in the `req.user` property. Try this:

```
function isLoggedIn(req, res, next){
  if(!req.user){
      req.flash("error", "Must be signed in first to access this page.");
      res.redirect("/login");
  } else {
      return next();
  }
}
```

Comment: Hey Ricky, thank you for your response. However using !req,user did not work for me. After trying to log in it states that req.user is not defined.

Comment: console.log the req object and check to see what is being sent. You may need to find an identifier of the user object that is logged into the session. It's possible to need to send the entire profile in the done() call back to access it.

Answer (score 0):

So turns out I was missing quit a bit of code to make this complete. First I needed to add the user schema for slack. Second needed to add a function to create the user and save it to my db and a function to check if a user had already signed in with slack and to just compare the ID instead of making a new instance of the user to the DB.  Also needed to update the serialize user and de-serialize  user.

Here's my schema

```
let mongoose = require("mongoose"),
    passportLocalMongoose = require("passport-local-mongoose");

let UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  local: {
    name: String,
    username: String,
    password: String
  },
  slack: {
    username: String,
    slackid: Number,
    name: String
  }
});

UserSchema.plugin(passportLocalMongoose);

module.exports = mongoose.model("User", UserSchema);
```

And than the set up for the passport strategies.

```
passport.serializeUser((user, done) => {
  done(null, user.id);
});

passport.deserializeUser((id, done) => {
  User.findById(id).then((user) => {
    done(null, user.id);
  });
});

passport.use(new LocalStrategy(User.authenticate()));

// Configure the Slack Strategy
passport.use(
  new SlackStrategy({
    callbackURL: "/auth/slack/redirect",
    clientID: keys.slack.clientID,
    clientSecret: keys.slack.clientSecret
}, (accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) => {
    console.log(profile);
    // Check if user already exist in DB
    User.findOne({username: profile.displayName}).then((currentUser) => {
      if(currentUser){
        // already have the user
        console.log('User is', currentUser);
        done(null, currentUser);
      } else {
        // If not, create new user in DB
        new User({
          username: profile.displayName,
          slackid: profile.id
        }).save().then((newUser) => {
          console.log("new user created: " + newUser);
          done(null, newUser);
        });
      }
    });
  }));
```

Also needed to update the routes for the auth and call back.

```
app.post('/auth/slack',
    passport.authenticate('Slack', {
      scope:['identity.basic'],
  }));

// OAuth callback url
app.get('/auth/slack/redirect', passport.authenticate('Slack'), (req, res) => {
      res.redirect("/QAApplicationHub");
    });
```

Hopes this helps others in need of passport.js help. For details info I recommend looking up The Net Ninja on YT. He helped me a lot with my code gap and helped understand what was actually going on.